# Checking if a Subitem value has changed (MFC)

Tags: mfc, propertygrid, bold, subitem

I was looking for a method through MSDN (more precisely in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb983759.aspx) which would indicate if a Subitem's value in a PropertyGrid was changed or not, but I couldn't find anything. Does this method actually exists or I should implement it by myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CMFCPropertyGridProperty::<strike>IsValueChanged</strike>IsModified()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc665572.aspx):

> Indicates whether the value of the current property has changed

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to use it in a method located in PropertiesWnd.cpp, but IsValueChanged() is a protected method. The code is something like this:

void CPropertiesWnd::Update()
{
    CMFCPropertyGridProperty * PropSel;
    PropSel = m_wndPropList.GetCurSel();
    PropSel->IsValueChanged(); //error! The method is protected
}

What should I do?
Thanks again!